# Powers of Hermitian Matrix commute implies that Matrix Commutes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

This could very well be a duplicate, so please close if similar. Working through old preliminary exams.

Edit: The original question is stated as follows.

Let $A$ be Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose $B$ is an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix. Prove that if

$A^3B=BA^3$

Then in fact

$AB=BA$.

I'm trying to prove a generalization.

Suppose $A$ is Hermitian, and let suppose there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$A^kB=BA^k$

Prove that $AB=BA$.

It's easy to show from the assumption that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial then in fact

$p(A^k)B=Bp(A^k)$

So that it's sufficient to find some polynomial $p$ that $p(A^k)=A$. To that end, $A$ Hermitian implies that $\sigma(A)\subset\mathbb{R}$. The spectral mapping theorem implies that the eigenvalues of $A^k$ are $\lambda^k$ for $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$. If $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ are the eigenvales of $A$, let $q$ be the interpolation polynomial of degree $n-1$ satisfying

$q(\lambda_i^k)=\lambda_i$.

Here's where I'm stuck. I want to conclude that $q(A^k)=A$. Is there a way to do that? Or is the interpolation polynomial the completely wrong approach.

Hints are appreciated if possible instead of answers!

Comment: Very good idea. Consider using the fact that, if $A=UDU^\star$ for a unitary matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D$, then $p(A)=Up(D)U^\star$, this should help you.

Comment: Yep yep. I see it now. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad it helped

Comment: I don't follow... this is from an old prelim exam-- they want you to prove an impossible statement?  That said, you may as well try to prove it for the case where $k$ is an odd integer.  Assuming both matrices are Hermitian, then the statement is true for odd k.

Comment: @user8675309, see accepted answer and comment. They did ask for $k=3$, I just was missing assumptions in my attempt at a generalization.

Comment: you really should have stated in OP that your formulation of the problem was a personal conjecture. Further you really should prove to yourself that this statement is true for odd $k$.  It comes down to the fact that $x\mapsto x^k$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ is injective for odd $k$ and *not injective* for even $k$. Since Hermitian matrices behave a lot like real numbers, in some sense this shouldn't be that surprising.  (Note that $B$ needn't be stated to be Hermitian, though the overall result is a lot nicer in the case that it is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false: take a self-adjoint projection $P$ and any matrix $B$ which does not commute with $P$.  Then $B$ does not commute with
$$
A= 2P-1
$$
either.  However $A^2=1$, so clearly $A^2$ and $B$ commute.

On the other hand the statement becomes true if $A$ is assumed positive.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. The interpolation polynomial $q$ cant exist when $A$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda, -\lambda$ and $k$ even.

To be fair for the examiners, they had k=3 specifically. I tried to generalize, but clearly extra conditions are needed!